# Dataset modification (large number of data)

Tags: r, dataset

I am doing a research on the influence of extreme weather events on migration. 
I am now building my dataset which looks like this:

[dataset:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvcmJ.png)

I need to create a new dataset which would give me the number of occurrences, total deaths and total affected for a period of 5 years (which would be the sum of the events that occurred during this period). 
In other words, I would like to create a table that would look like this: 
[desired dataset:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bYrh.png)

I could do that by hand with excel, but the number of data is too important (the number of countries/ regions included is more than 200). Therefore, I need to use R. 
Do you have an idea of how I could proceed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Picutres of data aren't very useful. Better to give a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We also assume you've made some attempt to solve the problem yourself. Show the code you tried and describe exactly where you got stuck. Stack Overflow is not just a place to get people to do you work for you, we are here to help answer specific programming questions.

Comment: Read about `cut`, then group by sum.